# Another representation for $\zeta(n)(2^n-1)$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, riemann-zeta

How can we write $\zeta(n)(2^{n}-1)$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $n \geq 1$ in other form?

I wrote the term as $$2^n\left(1-\frac{1}{2^n}\right)\zeta(n)= 2^n\frac{1}{\sum_{r=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{nr}}}\sum_{r=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(r+1)^n}$$

After this step, I don't know how shall I proceed. Any ideas/suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: "In another form" is so ambiguous. To someone who learned about this, it is obvious what this meant, but it is impossible to someone who hasn't...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\zeta(n) = 1 + 1/2^n + 1/3^n + \cdots $, we know that for $n>1$ the series converges absolutely therefore we can rearrange it without changing the limit value. So $$(1- \frac 1{2^n})(1+ \frac 1{2^n} + \frac 1{3^n} + \cdots ) = 1+ \frac 1{2^n} + \frac 1{3^n} + \cdots - ( \frac 1{2^n} + \frac 1 {4^n} + \frac 1 {6^n} + \cdots ) = 1 + \frac 1 {3^n} + \frac 1 {5^n} + \cdots $$

So we have $\zeta(n)(2^n -1 ) = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{2^n}{(2k+1)^n} = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(k+\frac 12)^n}$

Comment: This is an easy way! no need for fancy theorems. Thanks!